# Google Adsense Resubmit Problem Error Email Aready Exist

Tags: adsense

I'm trying to resubmit my website to Google AdSense and it's giving the following error again and again:

> A user with the email you specified
>   already exists    Please select a
>   different Google Account login to
>   access this account.

How to resolve this issue?
I have changed my password, recovered it but still not working.

Comment: did you contact google about this?

Comment: yes i have but no response at all

Answer (score 0):

You could try logging in to the account associated with the email address you are trying. It sounds like you're trying to create an account using an email address that you have already used to create a different account.

Comment: i submit a site abc.com using def@gmail.com ... they reject ...now i again resubmit abc.com using same email ... then that error appearing ...i don't want to create any other email